# Wait for the View to be entirely generated before using CoffeeScript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a View page with loops that create inputs. These inputs are manipulated through CoffeeScript when the `blur` signal is triggered. I would like to wait that the ruby loop generates all of my inputs and then launch my script. It works when using the inputs but it doesn't at the initialization.

```
$(document).ready ->
$('body').on 'blur', 'input', ->
arr = [
  'nb_kms'
  'parkings'
  'trains'
  'taxis'
  'metros'
  'meals'
  'hotels'
  'amounts'
  'o_ns'
  'clients'
]
name = $(this).attr('name').slice(0, -2)
if jQuery.inArray(name, arr) != -1
  total = 0
  $('input[name=\'' + $(this).attr('name') + '\']').each ->
    total += parseInt($(this).val())
    return
  $('#' + name + 'Total').text total
return
$('input[name=\'' + $(this).attr('name') + '\']').first().trigger 'blur'
return
```

The last line triggers the `blur` signal but nothing is detected. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
arr = [
'nb_kms'
'parkings'
'trains'
'taxis'
'metros'
'meals'
'hotels'
'amounts'
'o_ns'
'clients'
]

$(document).ready ->
  $('body').on 'blur', 'input', ->
 name = $(this).attr('name').slice(0, -2)
if jQuery.inArray(name, arr) != -1
  total = 0
  $('input[name=\'' + $(this).attr('name') + '\']').each ->
    total += parseInt($(this).val())
    return
  $('#' + name + 'Total').text total
return
alert name + '[]'
$('input[name=\'' + name + '[]\']').first().trigger 'blur'
return

$(document).ready ->
  $.each arr, (index, value) ->
    $('input[name=\'' + value + '[]\']').first().trigger 'blur'
  return
return
```

I had to put my `trigger` call in a second `$(document).ready`. I don't know why it wasn't working inside the first one.
I am sorry for the indentation, I don't know how to make it properly like CoffeeScript (pasting the code breaks the indentation).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you posted the exact indentation from your coffeescript file, then you need to be indenting your `$('body').on 'blur', 'input', ->` handler underneath the `$(document).ready ->` line. This will make sure the handler isn't defined until the document is fully loaded. Also, you need to then indent the body of your handler as well:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('body').on 'blur', 'input', ->
    arr = [
      'nb_kms'
      'parkings'
      'trains'
      'taxis'
      'metros'
      'meals'
      'hotels'
      'amounts'
      'o_ns'
      'clients'
    ]
    name = $(this).attr('name').slice(0, -2)

    # etc...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I did not posted with the exact indentation. Mine was like yours, and the script works when I manually blur an input. However it is not called at the initialization. Could it be because of the way Rails is implemented?